# what's the way to get Timestamp in Google App maker?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have a form. User fill up the form. which saves the data and send email. The datasource is in manual save mode. I was trying to save timestamp when the user use the form & send email. Then sort the data using the Timestamp field. I have a number field called Timestamp.(Tried using date field too) I'm saving the data as

```
OnBeforeSave :: record.Timestamp = Date.now();
```

But It's not saving the time. I'm not getting any error, but when I try to see it in table of data. The field is empty.  what am I doing wrong??
Let me know If you need anything else.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code? How do you insert in your table?

Comment: Just solved. It wasn't saving the data because the datasource was in manual save mode. But I wasn't calling datasource.savechanges() when saving the data..

Answer (score 3):

Realization:: 
whenever the datasource is in manual save mode you have to call

> datasource.saveChanges();

every time you want to save something. I have added

```
app.datasources.DataSourceName.item.DateValue = Date.now().toString();
app.datasources.DataSourceName.saveChanges();
```

in my client script. Solved the problem. 
N.B. - I have added toString() because I wanted to save my TimeStamp value as a string.